# source code changes either through Git or Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

> Our requirement is as follows - We are using Git and Jenkins We would
>   like to find out the source code changes from last successful build
>   and current changes which are there on github. ( Branch is same ) This
>   change list we want to send in email ( not as attachment )
>
> We have tried using git diff, email-ext plugin of jenkins. What could
>   be the different ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a combination of *git hooks* and the *Jenkins Remote JSON API*.

You can get information using the JSON API for the last successful build with a URL like this:

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/job/<test_name>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json
```

*JSON* will get returned as a result of *GET*'ing that URL. Inside of that *JSON* will be a hash entitled *buildsByBranchName*. Inside of that will be at least one, possibly more branches listed. You may want *origin/master*, although it will depend the branch you're merging into. Inside of that is an attribute named *revision* and inside that, *SHA1*. This can then be used in a *git diff*.

With the *git hooks*, I'd recommend using the *post-receive* hook. This is essentially a *bash* script, but it can wrap a more complex script, such as *Python*. One thing to keep in mind here is that if the current commit is a merge, what you want to check out may actually be one or two commits above the current one.

In any case, say you wrap a *Python* script inside the *post-receive* hook. Inside that *Python* script, you can add code that calls the *JSON* URL I mentioned above to determine the *commit hash* for the last successful build.

Then you can use that in conjunction with the latest commit hash (which you can get from within the git hook using the standard git command line tools, of which there are a variety of methods to accomplish this) and then do a *git diff* using the commit hash you got the for last successful build and the most recent build to get the changes between them.

You can then email these changes to the list of people you would like from within the script.